# Android Studio with Crosswalk and Google Play Games: White screen on startup

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games, crosswalk

I am attempting to implement Google Play Games integration into an app which I have created with Crosswalk (I am not using Cordova or any other libraries besides Crosswalk). I had initially gotten in to a state where, on my Android 4.2.2 test device, I could launch the game and unlock achievements just fine. When I tested in airplane mode, however, I would be greeted with nothing but a white screen and vague and unhelpful errors in logcat.

I have now updated a device to 5.0.1, and this device does the same white screen problems and gives the same logcat errors, except always, regardless of internet connectivity. It is worth noting that the 4.2.2 error still played the audio but failed to display any image, while the 5.0.1 device simply leaves me on a white screen with no feedback whatsoever.

Here is a logcat of a failed launch on 5.0.1:

```html
01-18 21:24:58.263 21216-21216/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
01-18 21:24:58.263 21216-21216/? E/Zygote: v2
01-18 21:24:58.263 21216-21216/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10255
01-18 21:24:58.263 21216-21216/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
01-18 21:24:58.263 21216-21216/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SCH-I545_5.0.1_0022
01-18 21:24:58.273 21216-21216/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
01-18 21:24:58.273 21216-21216/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-18 21:24:58.534 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.cameronseid.pegasausage-1/base.apk
01-18 21:24:58.544 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/ActivityThread: Application com.cameronseid.pegasausage is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-18 21:24:58.544 21216-21223/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/art: Debugger is active
01-18 21:24:58.764 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
01-18 21:24:58.764 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
01-18 21:24:58.884 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/XWalkLib: Init embedded mode
01-18 21:24:58.884 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/XWalkLib: lib version, api:5, min api:5
01-18 21:24:58.884 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/XWalkLib: app version, api:5, min api:5
01-18 21:24:58.884 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/XWalkLib: XWalk core version matched
01-18 21:24:58.974 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/cr.library_loader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 9883-9885)
01-18 21:24:58.974 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/cr.library_loader: Expected native library version number "", actual native library version number ""
01-18 21:24:58.974 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/XWalkLib: XWalk core architecture matched
01-18 21:24:58.974 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/XWalkLib: Running in embedded mode
01-18 21:24:58.974 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/XWalkLib: Init core bridge
01-18 21:24:59.405 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/cr.library_loader: Expected native library version number "", actual native library version number ""
01-18 21:24:59.405 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(121)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-18 21:24:59.405 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/cr.BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
01-18 21:24:59.415 21216-21299/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/ResourceExtractor: Extracting resource /data/data/com.cameronseid.pegasausage/app_xwalkcore/paks/xwalk.pak
01-18 21:24:59.465 21216-21299/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/ResourceExtractor: Extracting resource /data/data/com.cameronseid.pegasausage/app_xwalkcore/icudtl.dat
01-18 21:24:59.675 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-18 21:24:59.685 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
01-18 21:24:59.685 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/icudtl.dat: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
01-18 21:24:59.715 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                         OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                                         Build Date: 01/24/15 Sat
                                                                         Local Branch: AF11_RB1_AU15
                                                                         Remote Branch: 
                                                                         Local Patches: 
                                                                         Reconstruct Branch: 
01-18 21:24:59.805 21216-21365/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/cr.media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
01-18 21:24:59.845 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage E/chromium: [ERROR:xwalk_platform_notification_service.cc(103)] Not implemented reached in virtual bool xwalk::XWalkPlatformNotificationService::GetDisplayedPersistentNotifications(content::BrowserContext*, std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >*)
01-18 21:24:59.855 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage E/chromium: [ERROR:xwalk_browser_context.cc(79)] Failed to read preference, error num: 0
01-18 21:24:59.925 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-18 21:24:59.975 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
01-18 21:24:59.975 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
01-18 21:24:59.995 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
01-18 21:24:59.995 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
01-18 21:25:00.005 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
01-18 21:25:00.005 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ima
01-18 21:25:00.005 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
01-18 21:25:00.005 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
01-18 21:25:00.035 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
01-18 21:25:00.035 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
01-18 21:25:00.045 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
01-18 21:25:00.045 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
01-18 21:25:00.055 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
01-18 21:25:00.055 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7
01-18 21:25:00.055 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv8
01-18 21:25:00.065 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp43
01-18 21:25:00.065 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/sorenson
01-18 21:25:00.075 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
01-18 21:25:00.095 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
01-18 21:25:00.135 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
01-18 21:25:00.215 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
01-18 21:25:00.215 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
01-18 21:25:00.235 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-18 21:25:00.285 21216-21441/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
01-18 21:25:00.365 21216-21441/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-18 21:25:00.375 21216-21441/com.cameronseid.pegasausage D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-18 21:25:00.466 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-18 21:25:00.486 21216-21466/com.cameronseid.pegasausage E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-18 21:25:00.646 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1325994a time:21141554
01-18 21:25:01.527 21216-21216/com.cameronseid.pegasausage I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1325994a time:21142439
```

I have tried editing permissions, adjusting SDK target and minimum versions, trying different versions of Crosswalk and Google Play services, all to no avail. I am completely lost.

Comment: two things stand out from the logcat. one - it appears that the crosswalk is using a notification system which will need an internet connection. It might be worth disabling this service (sorry I don't know how or if its even possible) and two - there's no bluetooth permissions set, however I don't think this would be affecting the white screen...

Comment: I have tried commenting out the lines which initialize the GoogleApiClient, and the same problem persists - telling me it's not a google play problem. This happens with or without internet on 5.0.1, though 4.2.2 worked fine with internet and failed to display anything without internet.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a black screen of death when using crosswalk on a linux machine that was only using onboard graphics card.

Turns out that using "Software graphics" instead of "Hardware graphics" in the advanced settings of AVD manager for the emulator did the trick.

Not sure how the system exposes the hardware to the emulator, but if you don't have a good card with latest drivers, try using software graphics support!